# How to detect the state of a network interface whether it is down, blocked or live

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, network-interface

How to detect the state of a network interface whether it is down, blocked or live?
I got code for checking whether it is up / down using ethtool but i want to know whether that Port is blocked or Live for Fast Fail over Group.Is there any Flag for that checking ?

Comment: Is the network routing not supposed to do all that for you?  If one route to a host becomes unavailable, it will try another, no?

Comment: I want to know the code for that @ Martin James

Comment: blocked means **stp(spanning tree protocol) blocked**.some struct net_bridge_port  contain stp states...but how can i get it from there and use it in my programme